# Writing EOF (End of File) on Windows 7 with bootcamp

Tags: keyboard, windows, text-input, internationalization

I'm looking for a way to input the EOF char into the command line on my MacBook Pro with Windows 7 running in Boot Camp.
I've tried several suggested shortcuts and the on-screen keyboard but none of it works.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to enter an EOF. If you're not on an empty line, you'll need to press that shortcut twice, once to flush the buffer of the current line, and the second to send the actual EOF.